# how to make android sweeping second hand on analog clock?

Tags: android

I'm a newbie in android programing. Is there a way to make this analog clock with second hand do a sweeping (chronograph) movement instead of quartz?

Any sample to download?

I'm using this code for the clock:

```
public class SecondHand extends Activity {
// private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
protected static final String TAG = SecondHand.class.getName();
private ImageView img;
Handler mHandler;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Thread myThread = null;
    Runnable runnable = new CountDownRunner();
    myThread = new Thread(runnable);
    myThread.start();

}

private void doPlay(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.v("log_tag", "this is seocond thread");

        }
    }).start();
}
public void doRotate() {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Date dt = new Date();
                int hours = dt.getHours();
                int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
                img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgsecond);
                RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation((seconds - 1) * 6, seconds * 6,
                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

                rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

                img.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error msg is " + e.toString());

            }
        }
    });
}

class CountDownRunner implements Runnable {
    // @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                // Log.v("log_tag", "Roate is going");
                doRotate();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                doPlay();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                // Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error is " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
       protected static final String TAG = SecondHand.class.getName();
       private ImageView img;
       Handler mHandler;

       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       Thread myThread = null;

        Runnable runnable = new CountDownRunner();
        myThread = new Thread(runnable);
        myThread.start();

 }

public void doRotate() {

 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
 try {

 Date dt = new Date();
 int hours = dt.getHours();
 int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
 int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
 String curTime = hours + ":" + minutes + "::" + seconds;
 Log.v("log_tag", "Log is here Time is now" + curTime);
 img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgsecond);
 RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(
   (seconds - 1) * 6, seconds * 6,
   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

 rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
 rotateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
 rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

 img.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
} catch (Exception e) {

  }
 }
});
}

class CountDownRunner implements Runnable {
// @Override
public void run() {
 while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
 try {

  doRotate();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
 } catch (Exception e) {
  Log.e("log_tag", "Error is " + e.toString());
  }
 }
}
}
```

**xml file:**

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center">

        <AnalogClock android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:hand_minute="@drawable/widgetminute"                                   
                     android:id="@+id/AnalogClock" 
                      android:dial="@drawable/widgetdial"
                     android:hand_hour="@drawable/widgethour"  
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
       </AnalogClock>
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/widgetseocond1" android:id="@+id/imgsecond"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I got a private question for you. Can I email it to you? Your email?

Comment: I've tried adding this to a clock widget I created a while back, but my secon hand does not move. Is there a mapping I'm missing?
I also added a SecondHand reference to my main activity and called that class's onCreate in the main activity's onCreate but still nothing.
Also acording to logcat the onCreate and doRotate methods are never called.